# Sata Power Connection Broken Off but Pins are ok

Tags: hard-drive, sata, power

So, that crappy plastic connector holder on my hard drive broke off while I was moving drives around.

Does anyone have any suggestion on a work around, I've tried crazy gluing a Sata Power plug to it, and glue would get on the pins and cause the connection to fail. RMA request was denied.

[image]

if I hold the sata power connection manually, the hard drive will turn on and function properly.

Comment: Yeah, RMA requests tend to be denied if there's physical damage. Do you want a temporary or permanent fix? I've had reasonable luck with *brush on* superglue with a USB connector 'tongue' but this is more complex

Comment: any suggestions are welcome :)

Comment: I've had *reasonable* luck with brush on superglue (google it!). You want something with a minimal amount of spillover, slowish (but not too slow) glueing time, and a need to be applied on one side, not two. Test fit, apply brush on glue, press to fit. Should be good for at least one more plug in ;). Alternative might be to get a molex to sata connector, cut off the wires and solder each one to the corresponding wire ;p

Comment: eh, the soldering option I considered before, but the amount of time and effort isn't worth the drive, and I've already gotten everything important off the drive. Crazy Glue is kinda garbage glue to be honest, I wonder if someone can suggest something better

Comment: ahh. This turns into a product rec, which is what I was afraid of. Might be better for chat? locite makes a decent brush on superglue I am told.

Comment: You can always try to find the same exact model and swap the PCBs

Comment: The drive is too costly for that.